# Returning MySql results from a function with promise/resolve and async/await

Tags: javascript, mysql, asynchronous, promise, async-await

Edit: Question answered. Code is correct, just need to iterate through the results or access each element individually.

I'm writing a Discord bot with MySql. I need to check a table for the existence of the user before I can do other processing. The main body (not shown here) establishes the connection and collects the user commands, invoking the appropriate module. In this case, args[0] would have the value to search the table. The timing of the promise and await lines seems to be correct, as "Results" is printed after testUser returns. However, results is returning [object Object] instead of the rows (the table is not empty). Shouldn't resolve(rows) inside the function return the selected rows? I'm trying to avoid adding extra modules if I don't have to.

```
const discord = require("discord.js");
const mySql = require("mysql");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args, conn) => {

const results = await testUser(args[0], conn);
console.log("Results: " + results);
}

function testUser(userName, conn) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        conn.query(`SELECT * FROM user_master WHERE user_name = 
    '${userName}'`, (err, rows) => {
            if(err) reject(err);
            else resolve(rows);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: It should return your results as an array containing rows (=objects). What happens if you try to iterate over the returned result? 
`results.forEach( (row) => {
  console.log(row);
});`

Comment: You are right. Iterating it shows the results. The code works as is, the problem was between keyboard and chair. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked and I know what you mean, I often find it's me and not the code not working properly^^. I added an answer to your question and would appreciate if you would accept it as solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned `Object` contains the result of the query and can be queried as mentioned in the comments. To give a complete example, this would be your code including looping the returned result:

```
const discord = require("discord.js");
const mySql = require("mysql");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args, conn) => {

  const results = await testUser(args[0], conn);
  results.forEach((row) => { 
    console.log(row); 
  });
}

function testUser(userName, conn) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        conn.query(`SELECT * FROM user_master WHERE user_name = 
    '${userName}'`, (err, rows) => {
            if(err) reject(err);
            else resolve(rows);
        });
    });
}
```